# How can I load a Hibernate-mapped set as an unmodifiable set?

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, immutability

An application I'm working on uses Hibernate exclusively to fetch a bunch of persistent objects from a database to memory. The application is to refresh this in-memory snapshot from the database every now and then, and that should be the only communication with the database.

The in-memory objects are then used for a bunch of calculations. The calculations must not modify these objects. Except some class somewhere accidentally did, and I had to spend a day hunting down the bug. Now I'm wondering what the best way to make the entire object tree immutable is.

Suppose the class hierarchy looks like this:

```
public class Building { // persistent entity
    private String name; // hibernate-mapped property
    private Set<Person> inhabitants; // hibernate-mapped collection

    // getters
}

public class Person { // persistent entity
    private String name; // hibernate-mapped property

    // getters
}
```

I've prevented clients from accessing the database by:

- eagerly fetching all entities and collections
- marking all entities and collections with `mutable=false` in Hibernate mappings
- not providing any instances of the Hibernate session, or state-changing dao methods.

Now the error I'd like to prevent is, someone accidentally going `building.getInhabitants().clear();`. I can think of these options:

1. **Getter wrapping**: Make `getInhabitants` first wrap `inhabitants` in a `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` call, then return it.

   - Pros: Least work, least extra code
   - Cons: Feels hacky
2. **Wrapper classes**: Rename `Building` to `MutableBuilding`, `Person` to `MutablePerson`, and provide immutable classes `Building` and `Person`. Since my application has a clear snapshot point, I can fetch the records as mutable objects (as I do now), make deeply immutable copies and present that object tree to clients.

   - Pros: Straight java, no Hibernate magic. I get to use my favorite keyword: `final`
   - Cons: More code to write and maintain. Also, will Hibernate keep the mutable instances in memory?
3. **Hibernate mapping magic**: Use that one magic keyword to instruct Hibernate to wrap the collections it sets on my entity objects in `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` or equivalent. (Note: I use an xml mapping file)

   - Pros: Elegant, no extra code
   - Cons: Such keyword may not exist
4. **Hibernate extension**: Use that one Hibernate extension point to write my own object instantiator, and in there wrap the set in `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` before returning it.

   - Pros: More elegant than hacking my getters
   - Cons: Such extension point may not exist

Right now I'm leaning towards #2, mostly because I don't know if 3 and 4 are possible.

What is the best way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Option 1, for sure. It's not "hacky", and that's exactly why you abstracted the property access into methods, in the first place :-) Just note that you should use "field access" with Hibernate, instead of "method", so that you don't risk providing an unmodifiable collection to Hibernate.

Unfortunately, Hibernate doesn't provides a way to place unmodifiable collections, but I think you can do a @PostLoad event listener to modify all collections once the object is loaded.

Comment: This does seem like the best solution. I'll just have to come to terms with the fact that mutable classes are sometimes okay! :)